# Z77 motherboard with two DVI outputs?

Tags: motherboard

I'm looking to build a new computer with an Intel Core i7-3770 and will therefore be needing a Z77 motherboard. I currently have two monitors, and would like to use them both on the new system, however I have not found a Z77 motherboard with two DVI outputs. Does anyone know if one exists?

Comment: HDMI is compatible with DVI through a passive adaptor. DVI is huge, adaptorwise, so one's the most you'll get. Unless you need dual-link, on both monitors, go with a single DVI port and an adaptor. This is also a purchase question, and as such off topic for most of the SE family of sites.

Answer (score 1):

I havent seen any motherboards with dual outputs, they may exist though.  However, you are better off with getting a graphics card with dual outputs.  They will have more capability than any onboard graphics chip.

Comment: In theory, the current video adaptors handle up to 3 monitors fine. OTOH, DVI is somewhat depreciated, and take up a load of space. You can also, fairly trivially use HDMI to DVI adaptors. Depending on his use, a seperate video card may not be needed.